# Multivariate polynomials as matrix products?

Tags: matrices, polynomials, matrix-decomposition

Sorry if this is a silly question.  But if I have a polynomial in two variables, with the maximum degree of each individual variable no greater than N,
$$p(x, y)=c_{00}+c_{10}x+c_{01}y+c_{11}xy+c_{20}x^2+c_{02}y^2+...
=\sum_{i=0}^N{\sum_{j=0}^N{c_{ij}x^iy^j}}$$

...then I can write this as a product,

$$p(x,y)=\textbf{x}'A\textbf{y},$$

where

$$\textbf{x}=\begin{matrix}\begin{pmatrix}1&x&x^2&...&x^N\end{pmatrix}\end{matrix}'$$
$$\textbf{y}=\begin{matrix}\begin{pmatrix}1&y&y^2&...&y^N\end{pmatrix}\end{matrix}'$$
$$A=\begin{matrix}\begin{pmatrix}c_{00}&c_{01}&c_{02}&...&c_{0N}
\\c_{10}&c_{11}&c_{12}&...&c_{1N}
\\c_{20}&c_{21}&c_{22}&...&c_{2N}
\\...
\\c_{N0}&c_{N1}&c_{N2}&...&c_{NN}\end{pmatrix}\end{matrix}$$

This seems convenient, since the elements of A correspond exactly to the coefficients on each term of the function.

My questions are:

1) Is this a "standard" way of representing a polynomial of two variables?

2) Is there some convenient way to extend this to polynomials of more than two variables?

I don't know if there's a more general way to state this question, or if there is some theory out there regarding multivariate polynomials that I could learn, but any answers or links to resources would be helpful...I'm not quite sure what to Google for this.

Comment: You might be interested in this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_form#Real_quadratic_forms

Comment: Thanks.  Hmm, so this could be extended to an arbitrary number of indeterminates and degrees by setting
$$\textbf{v}=\begin{matrix}\begin{pmatrix}1, x, y, z, x^2, y^2, z^2,... ...\end{pmatrix}\end{matrix}$$
so that $p(x, y, z)=\textbf{v}'A\textbf{v}$ in the case of 3 indeterminates?

Is there any way to keep the indeterminates in separate vectors, as above?